# Code efficiency improvement needed solving problem 499 in Project Euler

Tags: matrix, algorithm, markov-chains, project-euler

I am trying to solve https://projecteuler.net/problem=499 by constructing a transition matrix and finding its steady state. Here is my code:

```
pmatrix[s_, m_, size_, iteration_] := Module[{matrix, matrix2},
  matrixtransformer[n_] := 0; 
  Do[matrixtransformer[2^(i - 1) - m] = N[1/2^i,20], {i, 
  Floor[Log[2, size]]}];
  matrixtransformer2[n_] := 0; matrixtransformer2[0] = 1;
  matrix = Join[
  Map[matrixtransformer2, 
  Table[Table[i - j, {i, size}], {j, m - 1}], {2}], 
  Map[matrixtransformer, 
  Table[Table[i - j, {i, size}], {j, m, size}], {2}]];
  (*construct the initial matrix*)
  fastmul[n_, t_] := 
  Module[{matrix3}, matrix3 = n; 
  Do[matrix3 = Dot[matrix3, matrix3], {t}]; matrix3];
  matrix = fastmul[matrix, iteration];
  matrix2 = 
  Map[matrixtransformer2, Table[s - i, {i, 1, size}]].matrix;
  N[1 - Plus @@ matrix2[[1 ;; m - 1]], 20]]
```

It works just fine with small parameters like $pmatrix[2,2,100,500]=0.25220849$
However, it is impossible to do the problem with matrix size of $10^9$.
What can be done to improve the code?
(PS:I am new with Wolfram Language, any suggestions on optimising the code will be appreciated also)

Update: I wrote a new algorithm seems to have a much better time complexity. But the ten thousand case would take a long time also, I don't know where the problem is. Here is my code:

```
pmatrix2[s_, m_, acc1_, acc2_, iteration_] := 
  Module[{}, ptemp[n_] := 0; 
  ft[n_] := Sum[1/2^i ptemp[n + 2^(i - 1) - m], {i, acc2}]; 
  Do[ptemp[i] = 1, {i, m - 1}]; 
  Do[Do[ptemp[i] = ft[i], {i, m, acc1}], {iteration}]; 
  1 - ptemp[s] // N]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it is up to 501 now.

Comment: Could someone please explain the sentence " The gambler is certain to win at least 1 pound, the starting value of the pot, at the cost of m pounds, the initial fee." to me? (I feel too dumb or too drunk, undecided yet)

Comment: @belisarius That means, when you spend m pounds to play the game, the worst case is that you have tail at the first time, then you collect the initial value of the pot, 1 pounds. That is "win at least 1 pound at the cost of m pounds". If you have head instead, the value will double until you have tail, then you collect the value of that time.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I find the writing quite obscure.

Comment: How is p2(2) roughly .2522? I pay my full stake on the first game. Heads I get nothing, tails I get 1 and game over. Either way I'm done.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau In the case of heads, the game actually continues.  Heads a second time, the pot goes up to 4 and you continue, tails you get 2 and can play again.

Comment: Please specify the parameters of the case you wish to solve.

Comment: @2012rcampion I don't follow that heads case. As I understood the setup, p2(2) means I start with 2 and ante 2 each time. So if heads came up I did not win anything and I have no funds to ante up for round 2.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You don't have to ante up each round.  Basically you ante up once, flip the coin until tails comes up, and then you win 2^(# of heads) pounds, then ante up and start again.  See the [St. Petersburg Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox) for the basic variant of the game.

Comment: @2012rcampion Thankyouthankyouthankyou. It makes sense now. (A lightbulb even came on over my head, but that was because it's getting dark and I turned on the lamp.)

Answer (score 3):

Making some suggestions for you code...

```
Do[matrixtransformer[2^(i - 1) - m] = N[1/2^i,20], {i, 
  Floor[Log[2, size]]}];
```

Note that I've used `N[]` for the values. Since we are not interested in the exact values using `N[]` reduces time.

And for the second part, you can use `MatrixPower[]` instead of iterating the multiplication. Its quiet fast. But the big problem is not there... That is with the size of the matrix.. Am also stuck here... But I think the trick is figuring out the Steady state matrix by using more math than programming... Anyways, the problem is enriching in so many ways.. so quiet happy to see a code here...

Comment: Hi ! As it is currently written it is not a full-blown answer rather than a comment. If you, for example, make a side-by-side pre/after and post it with timings that would be great !

Comment: `MatrixPower[]` reduces `AbsoluteTiming` by a factor of six for `pmatrix[2, 2, 100, 500]`.

Comment: Thank you, I have taken your advice and updated the code

Comment: Run times for parameters `2, 2, 100, 500`:

 - pmatrix as written in Question    1.65 sec
 - pmatrix with `MatrixPower`        0.27 sec
 - pmatrix with `MatrixPower` and `N` gave worse run times, even with precision less than `$MachinePrecision`  What are the values of `acc1` and `acc2` for your test problem?